# Not able to set the dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am not able to set the selected option of the dropdown from jquery and I am not sure whether the problem is with finding the dropdrown or issue with the code. I tried all different four ways but no result.
HTML

```
   <select class="form-control input-sm ddlFieldName" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FieldTagNameId must be a number." data-val-required="The FieldTagNameId field is required."  name="FieldName">
    <option value="">----Select----</option>
    <option value="1">Property Street Address 1</option>
    <option value="2">Property Street Address 2</option>
    <option value="3">Property City</option>
    <option value="4">Property State Abbrev</option>
    <option value="5">Property Zip Code</option>
    </select>
```

I have tried the following options

```js
     var setValues;
            $(document).ready(function(){
                setValues = function(fieldName)
                {
                   //1 st method
                   $('.ddlFieldName').val(fieldName);

                    $(".ddlFieldName > [value=fieldName]").attr("selected", "true");
                   //2. Method
jQuery(".ddlFieldName").find("option:contains(fieldName)").each(function()
                    {
                     if( jQuery(this).text() === fieldName )
                     {
                           jQuery(this).attr("selected","selected");
                       }
                    });
                    //3rd method
                    document.getElementById('.ddlFieldName').value = "fieldName";
                 // 4 method 
    $(".ddlFieldName > [value=" + fieldName + "]").attr("selected", "true");

                }
           
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: your snippet doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok we will start with method number 4.. you need to use `.filter()` and `.prop("selected", true)`

```js
var setValues;
$(document).ready(function(){
    setValues = function(fieldName)
    {
     // 4 method 
      $(".ddlFieldName > option").filter(function(){
      return $(this).text() == fieldName
      }).prop("selected", true);
    }
    setValues('Property City'); // run the function 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select class="form-control input-sm ddlFieldName" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FieldTagNameId must be a number." data-val-required="The FieldTagNameId field is required."  name="FieldName">
    <option value="">----Select----</option>
    <option value="1">Property Street Address 1</option>
    <option value="2">Property Street Address 2</option>
    <option value="3">Property City</option>
    <option value="4">Property State Abbrev</option>
    <option value="5">Property Zip Code</option>
</select>
```

With method number 2

```js
var setValues;
$(document).ready(function(){
    setValues = function(fieldName)
    {
     // 2 method 
      $(".ddlFieldName > option:contains("+fieldName+")").prop("selected", true);
    }
    setValues('Property City'); // run the function 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select class="form-control input-sm ddlFieldName" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FieldTagNameId must be a number." data-val-required="The FieldTagNameId field is required."  name="FieldName">
    <option value="">----Select----</option>
    <option value="1">Property Street Address 1</option>
    <option value="2">Property Street Address 2</option>
    <option value="3">Property City</option>
    <option value="4">Property State Abbrev</option>
    <option value="5">Property Zip Code</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. it was going nowhere and your suggestion works. Learnt something new. have a wonderful day :)

Comment: @user4895544 You're totally Welcome .. Have a great day too :-)